# is it possible to read a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, file

Hi all i just want to know if we can read a file using `javascript` like

what we do

```
fp=("r","path")
```

like that is it possible?

Comment: File from server or from client?

Comment: It depends on execution environment (there are even ones with this ugly syntax, Opera's Unite runtime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read txt file using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652737/read-txt-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I think its not a good idea to read a file locally with JavaScript. I recommend first upload it to the server and then perform the reading.

Having said that it is possible, but you restricted by what you can do.

Im assuming its a local file on the user machine, otherwise AJAX would achieve this for a server read.

It might be possible through

1. Windows Script Host Object Model(WScript.Shell) and
   when granted Prompt or Enable access
   to ActiveX the browser has elevated
   privileges (Enable through Tools >
   Internet Options > Security > Custom
   Level ... > Set Active X settings to
   prompt). If this is still to difficult, user could download something thats installed and then does the reading through Shell Scripting! ***Disclaimer:* Note I do not recommend this approach. Its not active for a reason and its so DIRTY (I feel dirty)!**
2. Cookies might also be worth considering. If you can store the information in a cookie the JavaScript would be able to read, write and update it.

   Found this code from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html scroll right to the bottom for the
   example.

   ```
   function createCookie(name,value,days) {
   if (days) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
   }
   else var expires = "";
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
   ```

   }

   ```
   function readCookie(name) {
       var nameEQ = name + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
           var c = ca[i];
           while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
           if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
       }
       return null;
   }

   function eraseCookie(name) {
       createCookie(name,"",-1);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not possible in a browser. Javascript runs in a sandboxed environment and doesn't have access to the file system. You might need to special plugins to be installed on the client browser in order to access his file system.

Comment: Some browsers support the File API, which allows the user to explicitly grant permission to the browser to read a local file; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, this is possible, even in some browsers.

#### Reading a local file, from a browser

**If** the browser supports the new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/), you can read any file the user gives you permission to read via an `input[type=file]` element. [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) | [Example here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063)

#### Read a server file, from a browser

This can be done on all major browsers using "ajax", more specifically the [`XMLHttpRequest` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). It's made a lot easier by libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

#### On a server, workstation, etc. (not in a browser)

You'll need an environment that provides file reading, such as [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: actually, XHR reads *entity* (in HTTP terms), not exactly a *file* (while server reads actual file)

Comment: @Worm: Yes, of course, but the point being that if you have a file on the server, you can serve it up via HTTP and read it via XHR.

Comment: Key is *have to serve*, just having a file somewhere is not enough

Answer (score 2):

Reading from client: [how to read a text file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652737/read-txt-file-using-javascript)

Reading from server: [jquery - Read a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981815/jquery-read-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Reading client files in javascript is possible with the new File API available in modern browsers. Check this site and its code: http://www.readfileonline.com/

Answer (score -2):

You can but then you have to use AJAX, which is Javascript for server side jobs.

Comment: AJAX is not "javscript for server side jobs". One good and correct definition is *group of interrelated web development techniques used on the client-side to create interactive web applications* (Source: Wikipedia) BTW the downvote is not mine.