# How to upload pictures in BackboneJs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model with many attributes, and image is one of them. How can I send a picture to the server alongside with the other attributes using the save method ?

Comment: Did you tried to save it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the FileReader API as described in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/jquery-js-get-input-file-image-in-base64-encoded) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript). However, it's been noted that FileReader isn't supported in older browsers, such as [IE<10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader), so if it's important to you to support these browsers you might want to send the image to the server after the user selects it, and have the server respond with a binary representation of the image *or* a unique id that refers to the image now stored on the server.