# How to checksum the file to be uploaded with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sha1, checksum, consistent-hashing

I want to checksum the files at browser side before uploading, then checksum and compare at server side to make sure the consistent. But how can I get the pure binary data of the file and checksum it? I tried the way below, but doesn't work:

```
let fileSelect = document.getElementById('file')
let files = fileSelect.files
let file = files[0]

var r = new FileReader();
r.onload = function(){ console.log(r.result); };
r.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
var file_sha1 = sha1(r.result)
```

Comment: What is your `sha1` function like?

Comment: Check this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript

Comment: @jayms, I use this npm library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library you are using seems to support string input only.
Find a library support binary input. Eg. [js-sha1](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1). And you should hash it in the callback.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  var file_sha1 = sha1(event.target.result)
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```