# Turning a html File (API Type) instance into a string?

Tags: javascript, html

With the HTML File API we can get a file selected via an `<input type="file">` element with `var file = evt.target.files[0];`.

How do we get the file content as a string (Something like `var content = file.toString()`.

I currently have this code which gets triggered by the `input element.onchange` event:

```
input.onchange = function handleFileSelect(evt) {

var file = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

console.log("RAW FILE: ", file);

var string = reader.readAsText(file);
console.log("FILE CONTENT: ", string);
```

}

When I select a file I try to log the contents this happens:

```
RAW FILE:  File
bundle.js:5293 FILE CONTENT:  undefined
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using the [FileReader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39515846/2341603)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a file cannot just be read synchronously like this:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    content = reader.readAsText(file);
```

Before we can read the file we first have to attach to the `onload` event on the file reader.

```
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      let content = e.target.result;
      console.log("FILE CONTENT: ", content);
    }
```

The trigger the file read:

```
        reader.readAsText(file);
```

The `content` will now contain the file content.