# Can I view and print the file with using JS without uploading file to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload, printing

I want to upload separate files and then view and print these files without uploading the server. If user click send button, send these files to the server.

Exp:

```
<p>
    <input type="file" id="file1">
    <img src="">Show thumbnail here
    <button class="print">Print</button>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="file" id="file2">
    <img src="">Show thumbnail here
    <button class="print">Print</button>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="file" id="file3">
    <img src="">Show thumbnail here
    <button class="print">Print</button>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="file" id="file4">
    <img src="">Show thumbnail here
    <button class="print">Print</button>
</p>

<button>Send All Files to Server</button>
```

[image]

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5492whns/2/)

Can I do this with only use vanilla JS without using a third party app?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can read the files using [File Reader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) then paint them into a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial), have a [print-only CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_types) that would hide (`display: none`) all the elements besides the canvas.