# strange filename callback after file selection finish

Tags: javascript, html, web, file-upload

I have this code which will display the file name after file has been selected:

```html
<input id="file-input" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.querySelector('#file-input');
  fileInput.onchange = function(){
    console.log('file name:', this.value)
  }
</script>
```

I prepared two windows shortcut file (produced by Desktop ---> right click ---> new ---> shortcut)

1. the first shortcut file

the target is https://www.baidu.com/ and the file name is [www.baidu.com](http://www.baidu.com)

after i select this file, the output is `C:\fakepath\www.baidu.com.url` in callback, which is working as expected

2. the second shortcut file

target is https://www.google.com/ and the file name is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

but after select this file, i expect it to output `C:\fakepath\www.google.com.url`  in callback, but it outputs something like `C:\fakepath\TQCJEVEM`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm still not sure about the *why*, but I can make a guess about *what* is happening.

When you create a windows shortcut (like you mentioned above) where the target is a Network Resource, it creates a [URL file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/url) that has a `.url` extension.
**NOTE:** Microsoft Windows does not display the ".url" file extension even though it exists in the filename. Therefore, URL files saved using Windows web browsers will appear with only the filename prefix.

A URL file on windows looks something like this:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,11
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
URL=https://www.baidu.com/
HotKey=0
```

When you upload the *baidu shortcut*, windows simply uploads the file with above content.

*HOWEVER*
When you upload the *google shortcut*, windows actually downloads a copy of the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) website landing page, stores it in the local cache somewhere in the `..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\..` folder and then uploads that cache file which could have its filename as a randomly generated string. Every new attempt would generate a new string for filename.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Edit:
To verify the content of the uploaded file, slightly modify your code using sample code from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56737666/9640017)

```js
function init() {
  document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

function handleFileSelect(event) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = handleFileLoad;
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0])
}

function handleFileLoad(event) {
  console.log(event);
  document.getElementById('fileContent').textContent = event.target.result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" />
  <pre id="fileContent"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your notice & reply；it seems your analysis is right, but i realy want to know the reason behind it; for what reason, it behavior so strangely;

Comment: I'm still not sure, if I do find something I'll edit the answer. Request you to add an answer too if you solve it.