# How would I edit a particular file with js

Tags: javascript, filereader

I want to edit and read a file using JavaScript using the FileReader API. However, all the tutorials I have found ask me to specify the file parameter using the value from `<input type="file">`.  Would I be able to set the file parameter as a file address like *'C:/Users/Code/example.txt'*.

FileReader API:

```
 function printFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: No, you would not, because if that was possible, then any website could try and automatically read the contents of any system or other files from known locations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to security concerns, you cannot do this in the user's browser, unless the user is uploading.
Here is a question that helps you read the file when the user selects it to upload:
[get the data of uploaded file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript)

It is however, possible on the server side using nodejs. Here is a sample code that does that on the server side:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('/Users/joe/test.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(data)
})
```