# Read contents of a file and print it to console using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am new to javascript and I would like to specify a javascript program to read from a file and print the contents of the file to a console?.This is the code I have written below and am getting an error,please what's wrong with it?

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

app.get('/',function(request,response){

     var fs = require('fs');
     var buffer = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('index.html','utf8'));

         response.send(Buffer.toString());

});

   var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
   app.listen(port,function()
{
    fs.readFileSync();
    console.log("Listening on"+ port);
}
);
```

Comment: Are you talking about Node?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to read a file using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028931/is-it-possible-to-read-a-file-using-javascript)

Comment: yes I am talking about node

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Have you tried anything?

Comment: no I havent done any research.Could you help please

Comment: no...I am kind off new in programming and I am using node.js not Ajax.

Comment: "no I havent done any research.Could you help please": you must be new around here. that's not how we do things...

Comment: Hi and welcom to StackOverflow. The community here will answer questions that show some research an knowledge of the topic. It's not a tutorial website. It is a resource to use when you have a specific problem, alongs the lines of ... "I tried to do this, but it didn't work. I expected result "a" but got result "b" instead. Where did I go wrong?" Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for more info.

Comment: What was the error? Have you installed [express](http://expressjs.com/) and read [Node.js API document](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) about `fs`? Sorry if this is rude, but I suggest you to read tutorials and documentations about JS, Node.js, and express. There are a lot of problems in this code.

Comment: Okay,I would go and read it.Thanks

Comment: P.S. If you are new to programming and/or JavaScript, I recommend you to learn from [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript). :)

Comment: Have seen the error,I used response.send(Buffer.toString()) instead of response.send(buffer.toString()).

Answer (score 13):

Use the `readFile` method of the `fs` object to read the file, then use `console.log` to print it:

```
/* File System Object */
var fs = require('fs');

/* Read File */
fs.readFile('foo.json', bar)

function bar (err, data)
  {
  /* If an error exists, show it, otherwise show the file */
  err ? Function("error","throw error")(err) : console.log(JSON.stringify(data) );
  };
```

For instance, if it is named `loadfiles.js`, run it as such:

```
node loadfiles.js
```

Comment: If you just want string do `data.toString('utf8')`

Comment: Keep in mind, there is also a synchronous version: readFileSync().  As the sample is written above, the script will end before the bar() function ever gets called.

Comment: @MikeHedman I do not understand what your point is. `readFile` is asynchronous and JS is asynchronous all over so there is a fit.

Comment: @SimonFranzen your answer is gold with `toString`, with `json.stringify` you get numbers as output which is not what we want.